# Resource sharing in a distributed java environment

Tags: java, mysql

We have a collection of resources to be distributed to users. 
Every resource will start in a state `<resource_id, READY, timestamp_when_this_resource_expires>`

Upon receiving a http request from the user, each web server thread should

1. find out the resource that is going to expire the soonest,
2. update the state of that resource to `<resource_id, IN_USE, timestamp_when_this_resource_expires>`

I am new to MySQL, I need some help. Two questions

1. How do I make sure *two web server threads do not pick same resource and give it to the user*.
2. I believe, I should use a connection pool in my web server.

Our platform:

- Java (and [com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html))
- We have multiple servers running on different machines
- our MySQL server is on a different machine.

Answer (score 0):

A connection pool won't work out of the box if you have multiple machines serving up resources. You could use a clustered cache such as Redis with Sentinel. This allows you to have keys with a TTL (Time to Live) and also allows for mutual exclusion.